# Extract part of string from row

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to run a kusto query and I need to extract offerThroughput from the row, please if you can advice. Thanks.

Sample data

```
"activityId_g","resourceDetails_s"
"dfcab056-2561-448a-9585-9bea6888e5ae","{id:H5Nd,_rid:H5Nd,_self:offers/H5Nd/,_ts:1657306008,_etag:0000ab18-0000-0300-0000-62c87b980000,offerVersion:V2,resource:dbs/sDVGAA==/colls/sDVGAKOxPdU=/,offerType:,offerResourceId:sDVGAKOxPdU=,content:{offerThroughput:1000,offerIsRUPerMinuteThroughputEnabled:false,offerIsAutoScaleEnabled:false}}"
"45c05db0-d503-42c3-be77-6a10c8fe7a68","{id:lEVo,_rid:lEVo,_self:offers/lEVo/,_ts:1659477250,_etag:00007500-0000-0300-0000-62e99d020000,offerVersion:V2,resource:dbs/sDVGAA==/colls/sDVGAK1hgXE=/,offerType:,offerResourceId:sDVGAK1hgXE=,content:{offerThroughput:8000,offerIsRUPerMinuteThroughputEnabled:false,offerIsAutoScaleEnabled:false}}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
datatable(activityId_g:guid, resourceDetails_s:string)
[
    "dfcab056-2561-448a-9585-9bea6888e5ae","{id:H5Nd,_rid:H5Nd,_self:offers/H5Nd/,_ts:1657306008,_etag:0000ab18-0000-0300-0000-62c87b980000,offerVersion:V2,resource:dbs/sDVGAA==/colls/sDVGAKOxPdU=/,offerType:,offerResourceId:sDVGAKOxPdU=,content:{offerThroughput:1000,offerIsRUPerMinuteThroughputEnabled:false,offerIsAutoScaleEnabled:false}}"
   ,"45c05db0-d503-42c3-be77-6a10c8fe7a68","{id:lEVo,_rid:lEVo,_self:offers/lEVo/,_ts:1659477250,_etag:00007500-0000-0300-0000-62e99d020000,offerVersion:V2,resource:dbs/sDVGAA==/colls/sDVGAK1hgXE=/,offerType:,offerResourceId:sDVGAK1hgXE=,content:{offerThroughput:8000,offerIsRUPerMinuteThroughputEnabled:false,offerIsAutoScaleEnabled:false}}"
]
| parse resourceDetails_s with * "offerThroughput:" offerThroughput:int *
```

| activityId_g | resourceDetails_s | offerThroughput |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dfcab056-2561-448a-9585-9bea6888e5ae | {id:H5Nd,_rid:H5Nd,_self:offers/H5Nd/,_ts:1657306008,_etag:0000ab18-0000-0300-0000-62c87b980000,offerVersion:V2,resource:dbs/sDVGAA==/colls/sDVGAKOxPdU=/,offerType:,offerResourceId:sDVGAKOxPdU=,content:{offerThroughput:1000,offerIsRUPerMinuteThroughputEnabled:false,offerIsAutoScaleEnabled:false}} | 1000 |
| 45c05db0-d503-42c3-be77-6a10c8fe7a68 | {id:lEVo,_rid:lEVo,_self:offers/lEVo/,_ts:1659477250,_etag:00007500-0000-0300-0000-62e99d020000,offerVersion:V2,resource:dbs/sDVGAA==/colls/sDVGAK1hgXE=/,offerType:,offerResourceId:sDVGAK1hgXE=,content:{offerThroughput:8000,offerIsRUPerMinuteThroughputEnabled:false,offerIsAutoScaleEnabled:false}} | 8000 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA62SXWvbMBSG7wP5D8ZXXZGw7Fi2LMhFIKELY2vpllAYxcjSsSMwdrDkbaHtf69dJ2maMhijRyDec3S%20eJAStjtZCRdCWv1L291SpQUvWq2Q04Cp20bCHKzQpUkNN7bRVfFpPPo5HjmduSqXIiM0wgGNfByGTOCEMoqTDETEGAMqwEXug1b8M/2mUNoclYEy53WeQ2O8PuKh1BruRzSekIgQhtJubMFJZyLzGe4FJpP%206lUUSBZnCesd9NJm3XXSdcXXATpszlVmPDNfX81m06kn67Lcu1%20u/9yo1dQbKn/stsAHebuvXCp%20mohkXVmoLH8YCjZN3RabbWu5f5y/NLerG2i%206qq18JqxqHq%20iueiNHDInLW2/i5FCW9en57cF67IDakkVGUEK0omOAzkBGcQxzgSPpEsh7iju%20daLtb1wHVQp1z7yJFrEsZxQMkJ15geaJ5yhSRRJPhPrv6muFv8C9ch8e9c2UdzvR%20PHp2taAy8/9jOb203zqXjnm/hOucRXVnn8hmKZy2UNwMAAA==)